# How to create a random number between -2.0 and 2.0

Tags: java, random, negative-number

I am trying to make a random point on a coordinate plane, and I want the x and y to be two random floating point numbers between -2.0 and 2.0

Given that I have tried

```
x  = (random.nextDouble() - 2);
y  = (random.nextDouble() - 2);
```

The above will only return (x,y) in the negative quadrant of the coordinate plane.

How do I make it so that it will reach all four quadrants equally?

Comment: You state in the title, that you want a random float, now you are working with doubles. How are x and y defined? If they are floats, than this is part of the problem. Please post the whole code.

Comment: @Turing85 double is a floating point type, so the use of "float" is reasonable and clear

Comment: @Bohemian not, if x and y are defined as floats.

Comment: @Turing85 They aren't floats; if they were the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a number in the range 0-4 (the same magnitude or your target range) then subtract 2 to align the start/end of the range:

```
x = random.nextDouble() * 4 - 2;
```

FYI small point: it is not necessary to use double constants, such as `4.0` in the expression, because when one of the operands of an arithmetic operation is `double`, java will perform an automatic (safe) widening of other types to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

`random.nextDouble()` returns a random value between 0.0 and 1.0, so if you just subtract 2, you will get a random value between -2.0 and -1.0.

You also have to scale the value - multiply it by the size of the range, which is 4 in your case:

```
x = 4.0 * random.nextDouble() - 2.0;
y = 4.0 * random.nextDouble() - 2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

random.nextDouble() only returns 0.0 to 1.0 you need to multiply it by 4 first

```
x  = (random.nextDouble() * 4 - 2);
y  = (random.nextDouble() * 4 - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: You only need scale it.  Subtract `.5` to get a number in the range from `-.5` to `.5`, and then multiply that by 4 and you have between `-2` and `2`.

```
x  = ((random.nextDouble() - .5) * 4);
y  = ((random.nextDouble() - .5) * 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

So random.nextDouble() returns a number 0-.9999 so you have to times it by your range -2 - 2 = 4

and then subtract 2 in order to get the -2 to 2

x = (random.nextDouble()*4 -2)

y = (random.nextDouble()*4 -2)